# Qual a origem da expressão "Mó boi"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, gíria

Cresci ouvindo essa expressão aqui em São Paulo, por vezes com algumas variações:

- Mó boi; *(É mó boi fazer esse trabalho)*
- Mó boiada; *(Mó boiada fazer essa cortina)*
- Muito boi; *(É muito boi essa conta)*

Sei que significa que algo é fácil de ser/fazer, mas qual a origem disso? Há alguma relação com boiadas ou com o próprio animal boi?

Comment: Vale lembrar que "mó" aqui é provavelmente um encurtamento de "maior".

Comment: @stafusa, como falante de São Paulo que usa "mó", digo que estás certo em relação ao significado — não sei da etimologia, mas aparenta ser uma hipótese. É um advérbio de intensidade principalmente; ex.: "eu 'to' com mó fome" = "eu estou com muitíssima fome", "mó trabalho pra isso" ~ "que trabalhão pra isso", "mó fácil" = "muitíssimo fácil". É mais expletivo do que a frase equivalente ou com "maior", por sinal.

Comment: Talvez possa ter alguma relação com os "carros de bois" que facilitavam o transporte nas sinuosidades na região de São Paulo. Quanto maior, mais fácil para puxar a carga. A questão é que este tipo de transporte foi usado em outros lugares no Brasil, o que fez manter esta expressão em São Paulo, não encontrei nada que possa vincular a expressão aos "carros de bois".